# Xamarin, Android: How to have my app open the developer options

Tags: android, xamarin

so I'm writing this app, that needs a buttons that says "Go To Developer Options". I've seen other apps do that already before, but I didn't find anything on Google.

How can I get my app to open the developer options autonomous? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    StartActivity(new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionApplicationDevelopmentSettings));
```

Comment: wow, that was super easy! just one question - what happens if dev setting isnt enabled yet? i have no way to check that atm :)

Comment: On my emulator it displays the settings page regardless of whether the device has had developer mode enabled. I can't test with a real device, as all mine have it enabled!